# Creating a variable that will eventually hold a piece of data to be used by all methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new to objective-c and I was just wondering how would I go about doing this?
Would I create a constant and simply fill it?

Example

I have a NSString *date. I fetch some data from the internet and now I have the date I want in this variable. I want to be able to use this NSString at anytime without calling a method that returns it at any scope within my program.

Thanks in advance!

Decided to use singletons based on answer...

Where would I put the code to retrieve the date from the internet that the variable will hold? Would it be here?

```
   static SingletonClass *sharedInstance = nil;

  // Get the shared instance and create it if necessary.
  + (SingletonClass *)sharedInstance {
if (sharedInstance == nil) {
    sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
}

//Put Code here??

 return sharedInstance;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Singleton pattern. [Here](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/) is tutorial. When you define it you can set variable NSString *date as property of singleton and use it.

**EDIT**
If you need to get data from internet just once - put your code

```
if (sharedInstance == nil) {  
    sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];  
    //here  
}
```

If you want update your variable data each time when you access to it you need to create getter for this variable and put code

```
- (NSString *)myDate {
NSString *date;
//here
return date;
}
```

Comment: Check my edited post if you please can, just had a quick question

Answer (score 0):

if all your doing is storing a single date variable, I would suggest using NSUserDefaults.  if you use a singleton then you'll have to persist the data between launches anyways. and NSUserDefaults is a singleton.  If you create a singleton then you'll to create another class and so forth.

to store:

```
NSDate *updateDate = [NSDate date];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] updateDate forKey:@"lastUpdateDate"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

to retrieve:

```
NSDate *updateDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dateForKey:@"lastUpdateDate"];
```