# Singletons objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a NSString *date. I fetch some data from the internet and now I have the date I want in this variable. I want to be able to use this NSString at anytime without calling a method that returns it at any scope within my program.

Where would I put the code to retrieve the date from the internet that the variable will hold? Would it be here? and then would I eventually make date= sharedInstance?

```
static SingletonClass *sharedInstance = nil;

// Get the shared instance and create it if necessary.
+ (SingletonClass *)sharedInstance
{
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }

    //Do I Put Code here?????

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need a singleton to do that.

Comment: `I want to be able to use this NSString at anytime without calling a method` - you're describing a global variable here, not a singleton. Also, why do you want this, and why do you want to avoid calling a method? For the most part, if your design uses global variables or singletons, it can be improved.

Comment: possible repost of [Creating a variable that will eventually hold a piece of data to be used by all methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548556/creating-a-variable-that-will-eventually-hold-a-piece-of-data-to-be-used-by-all)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a singleton pattern and can target an OS with GCD, then `dispatch_once` can simplify your singleton code, e.g.

```
+ (id)sharedFoo
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static Foo *foo = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ foo = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return foo;
 }
```

Depending on your requirements, you can override the `init` method to provide whatever additional initialization you need.

Comment: Why not `+ (Foo *)sharedFoo`?

Comment: @LarsSchneider, if you use `Foo *` instead of `id`, you have to re-declare the method for subclasses.

Comment: Methods that return instances of a class typically return objects of the anonymous type `id`.  This allows the initialization method to return an instance of a class other than the method's class.

Comment: Why do you suggest this simplifies the code? This actually leads to an extra line of code and you've not listed the potentially issues that this method mitigates, which gives the OP no insight into why would method id preferable to the other. I would indeed use this method though

Comment: If the class method returning the shared instance were the only method to override, that would be true.  Pre-ARC, many authors recommended overriding `dealloc`, `retainCount`, etc. Comparing that singleton implementation vs. the GCD-based approach, there is a significant reduction in amount of code.